# What's wrong with my nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

I try to add many hours in weekplan, so I code:
    #app/models/week_plan.rb
    class WeekPlan < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :hours
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :hours
    end

```
# app/model/hour.rb
class Hour < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :weekplan
end

# app/controllres/weekplan_controller.rb
class WeekplansController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @weekplan = WeekPlan.new
    7.times { @weekplan.hours.build }
  end

  private
    def set_weekplan
      @weekplan = WeekPlan.find(params[:id])
    end

    def weekplan_params
      params.require(:weekplan).permit(hours_attributes: [ :date_start ])
    end
end
```

And finnaly, **app/views/weekplans/new.html.rb**

```
<h1>New Plan</h1>

<%= form_for @weekplan do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :hours do |hour| %>
    <p>
        <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
        <%= f.select :user_id, User.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, include_blank: true %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :date %><br>
        <%= f.datetime_field :date %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :date_start %><br>
        <%= f.datetime_field :date_start %>
    </p>

    <p>
        <%= f.label :date_end %><br>
        <%= f.datetime_field :date_end %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

But, when I run my app, I get the error:

```
(undefined method `user_id' for #<WeekPlan id: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>):
```

I can't understand, where a bug hides?

Comment: Yes, it is, but I do not need it in **week_plans**, because **hours** has **user_id** column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `hour.label`, `hour.select` etc inside `fields_for :hours`:

```
f.fields_for :hours do |hour| %>       # <======= hour was not used, use it
    <p>
        <%= hour.label :user_id %><br> # <======= hour, not `f`
        <%= hour.select :user_id, User.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, include_blank: true %>
        # same with all other nested object's fields
```

P.S. Ruby processing of db data is bad:

```
User.all.collect { |p| [ p.name, p.id ]
```

Use db for it:

```
User.pluck(:name, :id)
```

Comment: I have an extra question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203572/nested-attributes-do-not-save-child

my child model not saved(